# am trying to display data that is present in column onto a dropsownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ToString(); // connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select location from events_det", con); // table name 
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["location"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString();             // to retrive specific  textfield name 
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        DropDownList1.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the problem you face please mention if any error ocuured?

Comment: when trying to load data from database onto a dropdownlist..its saying this error like object reference not set to an instance of object... i followed this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/fill-Asp-Net-dropdown-list-from-database-table-using-Asp-Net/

Comment: try the below answers, i think it wil help you. and do use using as fubo suggested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code should look like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
    {
        try
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ToString(); 
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select location, id from events_det", con))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);  
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "location"; 
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";         
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;   
                    DropDownList1.DataBind(); 
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

- Usually you only have to fill the `DropDownList` at the initial PageLoad and not every Postback
- if you want the `DataValueField` to be id, the id has to be a part of the select
- try to use `using` - that manages the `GC` and Connection closing for you
- `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` are the column names of your result
- no need to use a `DataSet` - if you select 1 Table you can use `DataTable`

Answer (score -1):

firstly without knowing what error you got, 
Let me tell you havent selected

`("select location from events_det", con);`

"id" field in your query so you cant use

`DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString();`

Comment: that means i have to use both location,id in my query right??

Comment: yes! the tutorial you followed uses * in its query which means it will retrieve all columns in the table